# basic java script scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var appContainer = {
        apps: new Array()
    };


    $("funcList div").each({
       appContainer.apps.push("testing"); // this does not work, why?
    })

    appContainer.apps.push("testing");
    )


});
```

is appContainer out of scope inside the each method?
this is the error im getting: [image]

thanks

Comment: Not directly related to your problem but `funcList` isn't going to match much (unless you have some weird, custom elements). Did you mean `.funcList` or `#funcList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple syntax error here as given below, also you need to have a look at the selector `funcList div`, whether `funcList` is a ID or a class, if so use an appropriate selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var appContainer = {
        apps: new Array()
    };

    //need to pass a function as the argument here
    $("funcList div").each(function () {
        appContainer.apps.push("testing"); // this does not work, why?
    })

    //extra ) here
    appContainer.apps.push("testing");

    console.log(appContainer)
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var appContainer = {
    apps: new Array()
  };

  //need to pass a function as the argument here
  $("funcList div").each(function() {
    appContainer.apps.push("testing"); // this does not work, why?
  })

  //extra ) here
  appContainer.apps.push("testing");

  console.log(appContainer)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<funcList>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</funcList>
```